# JavaFx width animation transition vs animation

Tags: java, javafx

I have this class that extends transition which animates the width of an element:

```
public class Resize extends Transition {

    private double width;
    private double diff;
    private Region region;

    public ResizeWidth(Duration duration, Region region, double newWidth ) {
        setCycleDuration(duration);
        this.region = region;
        this.width = region.getWidth();
        this.diff= newWidth - width;
    }

    @Override
    protected void interpolate(double frac) {
        region.setPrefWidth(width + (diff * frac));
    }
}
```

But I think that the same animation with no visual difference is acomplished with animation:

```
Animation animation = new Timeline(
    new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2),
        new KeyValue(field.prefWidthProperty(), 1))
    animation.play();
```

So what is the difference and which is the better way to do it?

Comment: If both works, use the one that fits your project better. Things I would consider are project flow and readability.

Comment: `Timeline` might be easier to create than to implement `Transition`. It looks easy but if you look at the implementations of the built-in transitions they all appear to use internal API that's not easy to replicate. Just trying it and I'm having issues getting the transition to play nicely with classes like `SequentialTransition` and `ParallelTransition`. Also, the `Transition` classes all seem geared towards using `Node` whereas you need a subclass: `Region`. Don't know how much trouble that might cause.